# How to display image from firebase storage into widget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I want to display the image saved in `firebase storage` into a widget that shows `profile picture` in my screen.
Currently I am able to get the `download url` but not sure how to make use of that url that will display the image into the widget. Here's the code that displays the `profile picture` UI that I want to update with image from firebase (ie inside `ClipOval` widget)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Edit Profile'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new Center(child: new Text('SAVE')),
          ],
        ),
        body: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              width: 410.0,
              top: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height / 25,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: user.profilePhoto == ""
                      ? Image.asset('icons/default_profile_icon.png',
                      height: 110.0)
                      : ClipOval(
                    child: _imageFile == null ? Image.asset('icons/default_profile_icon.png', height: 110.0,)
                    :Image.file(_imageFile,fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 110.0,
                    height: 110.0,)
                  ),
                ),
```

This is how I am fetching image from `firebase storage` which returns download url:

```
   displayFile(imageFile) async {

    String fileName = 'images/profile_pics/' + this.firebaseUser.uid + ".jpeg";
    var data = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName).getData(10000000);
    var text = new String.fromCharCodes(data);
    return new NetworkImage(text);

  }
```

Do I need to use `NetworkImage` or `cached-network-image` or `cache_image` widget to achieve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `NetworkImage` do the download

```
var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName)
String location = await ref.getDownloadURL();
return new NetworkImage(downloadUrl);
```

**update**

```
String _imageUrl;

void initState() {
  super.initState();

  var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName)
  ref.getDownloadURL().then((loc) => setState(() => _imageUrl = loc));
}
```

...

```
        child: _imageUrl == null ? Image.asset('icons/default_profile_icon.png', height: 110.0,)
                :ImageNetwork(_imageUrl,fit: BoxFit.cover,
```

Comment: I think `displayFile` method is similar to what you suggested. How do I make use of it inside `ClipOval` widget so that the image will be displayed ? @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. If you want to download the image yourself (`.getData(...)`), then you need `MemoryImage` instead of `NetworkImage`.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear earlier.I was not sure how do I use the download url inside clipoval widget under build widget. If you see currently it uses Image.file that displays the image from camera and gallery but doesn’t persist. How do i use NetworkImage or the code you suggested inside clipoval that will display the image from storage from inside of clipoval ? @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. I update my answer. Perhaps this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. There's a minor issue though, now whenever I select an image from camera or gallery, it's not immediately reflected inside `ClipOval`. If I go to other screen and then come back, then I see the widget updated with latest picture. Would you know why this could be happening ? I am expecting to see the image capture or selected from gallery to be shown immediately. @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: You're not showing the image from the gallery, you're showing the image from Firestore which needs to be downloaded from the Firebase server. You could show the image using `Image.file()` when you have a local path from the image picker and `NetworkImage` when you have a Firestore downloadUrl.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Earlier I was using `Image.file()` to achieve that. How can I achieve both conditions inside `ClipOval` ? @Günter Zöchbauer