# How to display image on screen taken from camera instantly?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-layout

Currently I am able to save and retrieve image from `firebase storage` onto the screen, but the issue I am facing is, if I click picture from camera, it's not showing immediately on the screen (although that image is saved). When I go back to other screen and come back, then the newly taken picture is displayed. But I want to show the image taken from camera instantly on screen. One of the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299919/how-to-display-image-from-firebase-storage-into-widget/53300016?noredirect=1#comment93492391_53300016) post is to use `Image.file` to display local picture and `Image.network` to display image retrieved from `firebase` but I am not sure how to use both these conditions to achieve what I am looking for. Below code shows the image downloaded from `firebase` (inside `ClipOval` widget)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Edit Profile'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new Center(child: new Text('SAVE')),
          ],
        ),
        body: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              width: 410.0,
              top: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height / 25,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: user.profilePhoto == ""
                      ? Image.file(_imageFile,fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: 110.0,
                  width: 110.0,)
                      : ClipOval(
                    child: _imageUrl == null ? Image.asset('icons/default_profile_icon.png', height: 110.0,)
                    :Image.network(_imageUrl,fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 110.0,
                    height: 110.0,)
                  ),
                ),
```

And this is how I am trying to display the image on screen after clicking picture from camera and then uploading it in `firebase`:

```
//display image selected from camera
  imageSelectorCamera() async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = imageFile;
    });

    uploadFile(imageFile);
  }

// Uploads image to firebase storage
  Future<String> uploadFile(imageFile) async {
    String fileName = 'images/profile_pics/' + this.firebaseUser.uid + ".jpeg";
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageFile);

    var downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    String url = downloadUrl.toString();
    return url;

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `uploadFile` returns a string which is not used by anything, or at least this is what I got by reading your code.

Assuming `_imageUrl` is your state variable for the download URL, just

```
String resultString = await uploadFile(imageFile);

setState((){
    _imageUrl = resultString;
});
```

If I understood what you're trying to do and your code, this should help.

You should trigger a change of state when your `uploadFile` returns the string and use that to rebuild the widget.

By the way, I suggest you to take  a look to `StreamBuilder`, which allow you to build (and rebuild) widgets according to a stream of data (you're using `Firebase`, I can tell you from experience that `Firebase` with `StreamBuilder` is quite awesome and fast).

If you are interested, check [this medium article](https://medium.com/@sidky/using-streambuilder-in-flutter-dcc2d89c2eae) and [the docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)!

You can find an example of building an app with `Firebase Firestore` and `StreamBuilder` [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e).

Comment: Awesome, that worked like a charm !! @magicleon and thanks for sharing the article and `streambuilder` example.

Comment: Glad to be useful! Happy coding!